# POST request failed with 405 Not Allowed when Spring Security is on

Tags: java, spring, security, websocket

Im using Java WebSocket client that subscribe to a Spring-Boot based server application. 
Everything worked just fine, but after adding support for Spring Security in order to authenticate and authorize users, the WebSocket Java client stopped working.
Im getting the following errors (POST request failed with 405 Not Allowed error)

```
19:56:49.813 [main] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler -
Initializing ExecutorService  19:56:49.819 [main] DEBUG
StompWebSocketTestClient - Connecting and subscribing 1 users 
19:56:49.886 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.s.c.RestTemplateXhrTransport -
Executing SockJS Info request, url=http:<//>localhost:9090/hello/info
19:56:49.923 [main] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Created GET
request for "http:<//>localhost:9090/hello/info" 19:56:49.941 [main]
DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for
"http:<//>localhost:9090/hello/info" resulted in 200 (OK) 19:56:49.974
[main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.s.client.WebSocketTransport - Starting WebSocket
session
url=ws:<//>localhost:9090/hello/912/d93d47eb2bdd4700a26c0e19e10a33df/websocket
19:56:49.974 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.c.s.StandardWebSocketClient -
Connecting to
ws:<//>localhost:9090/hello/912/d93d47eb2bdd4700a26c0e19e10a33df/websocket
19:56:50.120 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR
o.s.w.s.s.c.DefaultTransportRequest -
TransportRequest[url=ws:<//>localhost:9090/hello/912/d93d47eb2bdd4700a26c0e19e10a33df/websocket]
failed. Falling back on next transport.
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK ] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket     at
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.parseStatus(WsWebSocketContainer.java:619)
~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]     at
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.processResponse(WsWebSocketContainer.java:603)
~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]     at
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:300)
~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]     at
org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$1.call(StandardWebSocketClient.java:152)
~[spring-websocket-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]     at
org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$1.call(StandardWebSocketClient.java:149)
~[spring-websocket-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]     at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
~[na:1.8.0_45]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
19:56:50.122 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG
o.s.w.s.s.c.RestTemplateXhrTransport - Starting XHR Streamingsession
url=http:<//>localhost:9090/hello/912/d93d47eb2bdd4700a26c0e19e10a33df/xhr_streaming
19:56:50.128 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Created POST request for
"http:<//>localhost:9090/hello/912/d93d47eb2bdd4700a26c0e19e10a33df/xhr_streaming"
19:56:50.133 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] WARN 
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - POST request for
"http:<//>localhost:9090/hello/912/d93d47eb2bdd4700a26c0e19e10a33df/xhr_streaming"
resulted in 405 (Method Not Allowed); invoking error handler
19:56:50.139 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR
o.s.w.s.s.c.DefaultTransportRequest -
TransportRequest[url=http:<//>localhost:9090/hello/912/d93d47eb2bdd4700a26c0e19e10a33df/xhr_streaming]
failed. Falling back on next transport.
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 Method
Not Allowed     at
org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:615)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:573)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:544)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport$1.run(RestTemplateXhrTransport.java:128)
~[spring-websocket-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]     at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45] 19:56:50.140
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.s.c.RestTemplateXhrTransport
- Starting XHR Streamingsession url=http:<//>localhost:9090/hello/912/d93d47eb2bdd4700a26c0e19e10a33df/xhr
19:56:50.155 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Created POST request for
"http:<//>localhost:9090/hello/912/d93d47eb2bdd4700a26c0e19e10a33df/xhr"
19:56:50.163 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] WARN 
o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - POST request for
"http:<//>localhost:9090/hello/912/d93d47eb2bdd4700a26c0e19e10a33df/xhr"
resulted in 405 (Method Not Allowed); invoking error handler
19:56:50.166 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] ERROR
o.s.w.s.s.c.DefaultTransportRequest - No more fallback transports
after
TransportRequest[url=http:<//>localhost:9090/hello/912/d93d47eb2bdd4700a26c0e19e10a33df/xhr]
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 Method
Not Allowed     at
org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:615)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:573)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:544)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport$1.run(RestTemplateXhrTransport.java:128)
~[spring-websocket-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]     at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45] 19:56:50.167
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.m.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession
- Failed to connect session id=318180fa-47bc-5649-c136-db91a339837a org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 Method
Not Allowed     at
org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:615)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:573)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:544)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport$1.run(RestTemplateXhrTransport.java:128)
~[spring-websocket-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]     at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45] 19:56:50.170
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] ERROR StompWebSocketTestClient - Transport
error org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405
Method Not Allowed  at
org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:615)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:573)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:544)
~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]   at
org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport$1.run(RestTemplateXhrTransport.java:128)
~[spring-websocket-4.2.0.RC1.jar:4.2.0.RC1]     at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Here is the the Spring Security configuration file:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
            csrf().disable().
            sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
            and().
            authorizeRequests().
            //TODO: as a workaround for WS 401 error, tried but did not work: antMatchers("/hello").permitAll(). possible related to the StompClient URL which is ws://
            antMatchers(actuatorEndpoints()).hasRole(backendAdminRole).
            anyRequest().authenticated().
            and().
            anonymous().disable().
            exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint());

    http.addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).
            addFilterBefore(new ManagementEndpointAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

please note that I'm not using WebClient, thus my security configuration disable the Spring's default Spring LoginForm

Here is the WebSocket configuration

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
}
```

Here is the WebSocket Security configuration
(I tried many configurations - tried everything I found in the web, but it didnt work)

```
@Override
protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
    messages
            // message types other than MESSAGE and SUBSCRIBE
            .nullDestMatcher().authenticated()
            // matches any destination that starts with /rooms/
            .simpDestMatchers("/topic/**").authenticated()
            // (i.e. cannot send messages directly to /topic/, /queue/)
            // (i.e. cannot subscribe to /topic/messages/* to get messages sent to
            // /topic/messages-user<id>)
            .simpTypeMatchers(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE, SimpMessageType.SUBSCRIBE).denyAll()
            // catch all
            .anyMessage().denyAll();
}

/**
 * Disables CSRF for Websockets.
 */
@Override
protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
    return true;
}
```

And here is my Java Client

```
    List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(2);

    StandardWebSocketClient standardWebSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
    transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(standardWebSocketClient));

    RestTemplateXhrTransport restTemplateXhrTransport = new RestTemplateXhrTransport();

    //setting the authentication token
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("X-Auth-Token", token);

    restTemplateXhrTransport.setRequestHeaders(httpHeaders);
    transports.add(restTemplateXhrTransport);

    SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);

    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    taskScheduler.afterPropertiesSet();

    String stompUrl = "ws://localhost:9090/hello";


    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());
    stompClient.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
    stompClient.setDefaultHeartbeat(new long[] {10, 10});

    WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders(httpHeaders);

        WebSocketSession webSocketSession;

        logger.debug("Connecting and subscribing " + NUMBER_OF_USERS + " users ");
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch("STOMP Broker Relay WebSocket Load Tests");
        stopWatch.start();

        List<ConsumerStompSessionHandler> consumers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i < NUMBER_OF_USERS; i++) {
            consumers.add(new ConsumerStompSessionHandler(BROADCAST_MESSAGE_COUNT, connectLatch,
                    subscribeLatch, messageLatch, disconnectLatch, failure));
            stompClient.connect(stompUrl, headers, consumers.get(i), host, port);
        }
```

The application failed on the stompClient.connect() line
where:
host is the address of the Web Application server (Spring base of course) - in my case is 'localhost'. The 'port' parameter is the port that the Web Application server is listening on.
Headers: include 'X-Auth-Token' header

Here is the current pom.xml I'm using (well, it changed a bit since I wrote the post)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>my-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>

        <org.springframework-version>4.1.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>

        <app.version>1.0</app.version>
        <spring-boot.version>1.1.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Logging
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>-->
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>

        <tomcat.version>8.0.8</tomcat.version>

        <spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <springloaded.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</springloaded.version>

        <spring-security.version>4.0.0.RC1</spring-security.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.embedded</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PERSISTANCE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1101-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SECURITY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--ASPECT-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!--CONVERTERS-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JODA Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOMBOK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSON Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jsonSchema</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- TESTING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--JSON Doc-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jsondoc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsondoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsondoc-ui-webjar</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>${springloaded.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/dep.xml</descriptor>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>        

        <repository>
            <id>clojars.org</id>
            <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>closure</id>
            <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java-net</id>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

thanks in advance for your help

**Update**

I had the below LoginController as part of my project Controller classes. The /authenticate Controller is related to the POST method of the X-Auth authentication mechanism used by Spring Security. I found out that once this controlled has been removed from the project - the HTTP 405 Not Allowed error disappeared.
I have to admit that I have no clue as for the reason. I just used trial&error to try and find the issue with the 405 error.
Appreciate if someone could help me understand what might be the problem. tnx

```
package com.iotiki.controller;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;


@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginBusinessLogic loginBusinessLogic;

    @RequestMapping(value=ApiController.AUTHENTICATE_URL/*"/authenticate"*/,method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO) throws UnAuthorizedException {
        return "this method should not be called, since Spring Security should take over";

    }


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public LoginDTO getLoginDTO(){
        return new LoginDTO();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details. what spring version you are using? also, what is the value of the host property. does it include /portfolio in it ?

Comment: I've updated the post with the project's pom.xml file (it has many dependencies in it since I've tried many options). The 'host' value is just 'localhost' and it doesn't include /portforlio it it. Basically, I'm trying to understand what is the POST request that the client is trying to make as part of the handshake process with the server, which the server response is -  405 Not Allowed. tnx in advance for your help

Comment: This is not a case of 'failed to create Websocket connection'. It is a case of 'POST request failed with 405 Not Allowed'. The POST precedes the Web socket creation. Accuracy please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the x-auth-token approach works by allowing Spring Session to override the HttpSession implementation (to look in the x-auth-token header for the session id and to look up the session in Redis). Then Spring Security behaves normally (i.e. it tries to look up the current user in HttpSession).

However, the configuration you provided (reformatted for clarity)

```
http
   .csrf().disable()
   .sessionManagement()
       .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
       .and()
   .authorizeRequests()
```

is telling Spring Security not to consult the HttpSession. So the fix would be to remove the sessionManagement section.

```
http
   .csrf().disable()
   .authorizeRequests()
```

Comment: Hi Rob. Tnx for your answer. Unfortunately that wasn't the problem. Even if I removed the lines you have indicated, the problem still exist.
What I did eventually is to take your 'spring-websocket-portfolio' project example, change it a bit to work as Spring boot webapp, and start moving my POC project code into it. What I found out is that a LoginController that I've define in my project (see LoginController in the original question) was the issue that caused the 405 error. I have to admit that I have no clue as why it was a problem. 
Id appreciate very much if you could take a look. tnx

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue and I think it might relate to your issue as well. one of my `@RestController`s didn't have `@RequestMapping("/myendpoint")` on the class.
this alone was causing a `405 method not allowed` error for my websocket.

I couldn't figure the reason for this behavior either but "maybe" the absence of @RequestMapping on the controller was causing the requests from websocket ending up on this controller's endpoint, since the controller is only accepting POST requests by default
you would get `405 method not allowed`.

I believe if you had specified endpoints for your `@RequestMapping`s specially the GET type:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/me/myendpoint" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public LoginDTO getLoginDTO(){
    return new LoginDTO();
}
```

it would solve your problem.